# Deserializing XML from stream to List<T>

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

I have some data in an XML file which is being read through stream. I've got access to stream object using which I have to deserialize the data and populate a List. My model class is given below

```
[XmlRoot("invoices")]
public class Invoice
{       
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description", IsNullable= true)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice_date")]
    public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice_number")]
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "date_due")]
    public string DateDue { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And below is the snippet from the method which I am using to read the data

```
public List<Invoice> ParseRecords(Stream stream)
    {
        List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice>();

        try
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Invoice>));
            invoices = (List<Invoice>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
        }

        return invoices;
    }
```

The XML data contains invoices with a root tag called "invoices" and multiple child records with tag "invoice". There is no namespace defined for the root element and it can't be done as the XML data is received from an external source. The XML data is in correct format. The problem which I face is that when Deserialize() method is executed, it throws an exception saying 
There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
and the inner exception says {" was not expected."}

Can anyone please help me figure out what's wrong here?

Comment: Can you share your xml content/data that you are trying to deserialize

Comment: <invoices amount_type="" import_type="">
    <invoice>        
        <invoice_number>1234</invoice_number>
        <description></description>
        <invoice_date>20150329</invoice_date>
        <date_due>20150412</date_due>        
        <amount>0</amount>
    </invoice>
 <invoice>        
        <invoice_number>2587</invoice_number>
        <description></description>
        <invoice_date>20150529</invoice_date>
        <date_due>20150612</date_due>        
        <amount>0</amount>
    </invoice>
</invoices>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of achieving the result you are expecting is like below

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "invoices")]
public class Invoices
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice")]
    public List<Invoice> Invoice { get; set; }
}

    [XmlRoot("invoice")]
public class Invoice
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice_date")]
    public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice_number")]
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "date_due")]
    public string DateDue { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And your parse records function should like something like below

```
public Invoices ParseRecords(Stream stream)
{
    Invoices invoices;

    try
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoices);
        invoices = (Invoices)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex);
    }

    return invoices;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! You are a life saver. God bless you :)

Comment: I've got another question. If there is an XML attribute in one of the tags, deserializing always return null for that. For example, if amount has an attribute currency and I add a property Currency of type string in my model class, the value for this property is set to null after deserializing.

Comment: Your Serializable class will change if your xml changes.

Comment: Yes, I've added `XmlAttribute` decorator to the property but it's not deserializing

Comment: For me the key was to reset stream position to zero.

Answer (score 0):

there is some invisible code (looks like white space) in the data, it's maybe caused by the encoding.